# Rxjs switchmap cancels subscription too early

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, rxjs

I have this bit of code to track a position variable with the upstream event being a keyboard listener. I want to emit the 'starting' position so that the player is drawn on the screen before any real keypress is made, so I built this observable, which starts with a noop in order to emit the starting position without any movement:

```
$keyboardEvent.pipe(
    startWith(
      {
        key: Key.Noop,
        keys: [Key.Noop],
        keyStroke: KeyStroke.Down,
      },
      { key: Key.Noop, keys: [], keyStroke: KeyStroke.Up }
    ),
    tap(({ keys }) => (keysRef.current = keys)),
    switchMap(() => (keysRef.current.length > 0 ? $animationEvent : EMPTY)),
    map(() => {
      if (keysRef.current.length > 0) {
        playerPosition.current = updatePlayerPosition(keysRef.current);
        playerRotation.current = updatePlayerRotation(keysRef.current);
      }

      playerMovementState.current =
        keysRef.current.length > 0 ? "active" : "idle";

      return {
        position: playerPosition.current,
        rotation: playerRotation.current,
        state: playerMovementState.current,
      };
    })
  )
```

The issue seems to be that the switchMap operator cancels the $animationEvent as soon as the second starting event is piped, which seems to occur before the first event can emit to the subscriber. When I tap the event before the switchMap, this is the output:

```
{key: "", keys: Array(1), keyStroke: "Down"}
{key: "", keys: Array(0), keyStroke: "Up"}
```

When I tap after the switchMap, I get no results, even though I know that the $animationEvent is returned after the first event is piped.

Can someone please help explain this behavior, and if there are any workarounds? I would prefer not to have to use some buffered observable that has a window just big enough for the event to make it downstream, because that doesn't seem maintainable long term and also I just shouldn't have to do that to begin with.

Comment: Hi there! If it helps intuition-wise, the way I think about it is that when switchMap receives a new value, it takes it as a signal that any work being done based on the previous value should be scrapped and it switches to processing the new value. As for workarounds, it just depends on what behavior you need - for instance if the user's keypresses shouldn't do anything while the animation is in progress, just replace switchMap with exhaustMap.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What I’m looking for is to just emit a starting value when the main observable is subscribed to. After that starting value, keyboard presses will initiate an animation loop that will draw the player in a position related to the key press, and after idle the observable will complete (aka switch to EMPTY so that the RAF will stop processing). If I move the startWith to after the switch map, it’ll just reset the position after each key press which is also bad behavior.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it! I'll reply in an answer to have more space, will post in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing the discussion in the comments: I'm pretty sure what is happening is this:

- The first event is passed to `switchMap` and `$animationEvent` is subscribed to.
- Before `$animationEvent` emits any values, the second event is passed to `switchMap`, and as a result `$animationEvent` is unsubbed before it had a chance to fire any values.
- The second event maps to `EMPTY`, so at the end nothing is emitted after `switchMap`.

If I got it right and all that you're looking to do is add starting events, then adding `startWith` at the end of the pipeline is the way to go - it will just emit those two starting events as the first two values. If you see it emitting the two values more than once, that means that `subscribe` is called multiple times. One mistake that's easy to make that would cause this, is subscribing in a `React.useEffect` callback and forgetting to add `[]` as the second argument.

Comment: Ah, it looks like I made an incorrect assumption about how switchMap works, I assumed that everything after the switchMap would be a new observable, in which case startWith would happen again for every next switchedTo observable, and not the observable as a whole. This worked, thank you!

Comment: @jajabarr Anytime :)